# wix or installshield for asp.net application installer?

Tags: installation, wix, installshield

What is the best tool to create an installer for asp.net application?  My objectives are to:

1. Install an asp.net application on iisexpress
2. Install sqlexpress (as a prerequisite)
3. Configure IIS for my application
4. Restore data on sqlserver

Answer (score 6):

Either will do the trick, so it comes down to what your needs are, and how they stack up against each other

#### InstallShield

- Will guide you through the process a lot more than WiX, and so will get you off the ground quicker
- Has built in functionality for talking to IIS, SQL and a bunch of other sources
- Has built in functionality for installing a number of prerequisites, such as .NET. I believe installing sqlexpress as a prereq is supported.
- Can target InstallScript, MSI, or a mix of the two

#### WiX

- Is free & open source.
- Is much more flexible in how you organise your code. It uses XML like InstallShield, but unlike InstallShield you have pretty much complete control over how the code is organised, and it's generally much easier to compare and merge the code in your source control system.
- Is very extensible - you can hook into the compiler mechanism through WixExtensions
- Has functionality for talking to IIS and SQL via custom actions and syntax extensions
- Comes with Burn, a flexible and powerful bootstrapper, install chainer, and install host.  This can handle your prerequisite installation for you, and even host your UI.

#### Conclusion

Personally, I recommend learning WiX - the code is easier to manage for large projects over time, and you are less likely to reach that brick wall where stuff just can't be done because of how extensible it is.

However, it will take you longer to get off the ground because you have to actually understand what's going on to a greater degree than with InstallShield.

Comment: thanks for one day when i working with Installshield i know thats better in my country free or open source its funny word because all programs are cracked using and copyright not doing here

Comment: Well, as someone who enjoys not being sued, I always encourage people to use properly licensed software that has been paid for (where payment is required). And hug a puppy.

Comment: there is no payment service such as master, visa or another international bank in my country if i use licensed software i cant and there is no wayy , iranian people very like to use orginal software with orginal support

Comment: Ah, well as far as I'm concerned that does change things somewhat, at least ethically. A lawyer mightarogue differently, of course.

Comment: FWIW, InstallShield Limited Edition is "Free" (for Visual Studio users which I'm guessing OP has ).  It has setup prerequisites (SQL Express, .NET Framework... )  It can also consume merge modules which means you can create merge modules using WiX and inject capabilities into the InstallShield built MSI that InstallShield doesn't support  *AND* get the flexibility of organizing the code the way you want.  In other words,  leverage the best of both platforms when creating your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently migrating projects from various versions of InstallShield to Wix. You need to put more effort into Wix, but it is worth it in the long run. The problems I have found with InstallShield is it is relative expensive to license, and once you start using it you become hooked into paying out more money to upgrade it or get the latest version, because the person who used it last is no longer around, license keys have gone astray, there are not enough license keys anyway, a license key that used to work no longer does for some strange reason...etc, etc. Without a up-to-date and functioning license key InstallShield will not work.

Because an installation project is not something we use all the time, but when we do use it we need it to work, I have decided to junk InstallShield for something more reliable (in terms of licensing).

Comment: This sounds more like you have poor procedures in the workplace since you can't track down receipts and license keys to ask Flexera for support